# Cannot send message without a sender address Issue in 1 Environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I am having a problem in Laravel with my mailer. The weird part is the issue only happens in my production environment, it works correctly in development.

I have confirmed the proper environment values are set in production. I have also cleared the configuartion cache.

If I remove the environment values in the "from" line and replace them with hard coded values in production it works. So in development it works correctly with environment values in "from", in production it only works with hard coded value.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

my config/mail.php file is as follows:

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), 'name' => env('APP_NAME')],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
];
```

My .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXX
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=XXXXX@XXXXXX.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if `env('APP_NAME')` exists? `name` can be absent [according to docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#-From-Address-Errors) but I'm not sure if you can pass a null value.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include that section of the .env file, I have confirmed that App_Name does exist in the file.